# Identify 19th century font with italic uppercase N with ball serifs

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to identify a typeface from an 1800s book.  It has a strange shape to the uppercase N (and also to the A) with a ball serif where I wouldn't have expected one.  Does anyone know a font similar to this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the "ball serfis" are more commonly referred to as "[ball terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_terminal)".

### [Cosmiqua Bold Italic](http://www.linotype.com/1107020/CosmiquaStdBoldItalic-product.html):

[image: Cosmiqua Com Bold Italic]

Not sure what typeface it's based off of since this was designed in 2007, but it comes pretty darn close.

---

Another similar one I found:

### [LTC Law Italic](http://www.linotype.com/en/297095/LTCLaw-family.html)

[image: LTC Law Italic]